# How to Communicate between two stateful services service fabric?

Tags: service-fabric-stateful

I have two stateful services hosted on my service fabric.. I need to communicate from one service to another service using service proxy. Some thing like this

```
_proxyFactory.CreateServiceProxy<IRestoreStatefulService>(new
    Uri("fabric:/Itron.Cloud.ActionManager.ExDefinition.Services/BackupResStateful"), 
    new ServicePartitionKey(0), TargetReplicaSelector.Default, null)
```

I could do this from stateful to stateless service, but couldnt do the same between two stateful services..

Comment: It could be that you're not passing a correct ServicePartitionKey. What error message did you get?

Comment: That code looks fine, so either the service doesn't exist, the partition key is invalid, or the target service doesn't have a remoting listener set up. What happens when you run this code? Do you get an exception?